Would removing Java type erasure help to catch more errors at compile time?
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
List rawList = stringList;
rawList.add(10);

So the above code compiles with a warning, but breaks at runtime.  This was presented as one of the cases where removing type erasure in Java would have a positive effect (although I understand on balance we will never remove it).
My confusion is, we do type checking before type erasure occurs. So how can deciding not to do some later step in the compilation process help us to find problems we previously couldn't find?
Case 1:

do type checking, fail to find the error above
do type erasure

Case 2:

do type checking, manage to find the error above

But if that's possible, why not just do case 3:

do type checking, manage to find the error above
do type erasure

I hope it's clear what I don't understand.

This is exactly why compile warnings are so important.  Very often, a compile warning means "this is likely to break at run time - proceed at your own risk".

If you wanted to prevent that error at compile-time, it's not type erasure that's the issue; it's using raw types. The compiler warns you about using raw types, but doesn't prevent you if you ignore the warnings.

This is what I would also have said.  If we removed type erasure, but kept raw types, this issue would persist?  This example has basically nothing to do with type erasure.  The only compilation error we fix is an overloaded method with different list types collapsing into the same method signature.  Would that be right?

Having those types in generics is a very useful language feature and an awesome thing the compiler knows about. If your code only works when you remove the types, it is almost certainly going to throw an exception during runtime, so you just made the problem occur later.

"removed type erasure, but kept raw types" doesn't make much sense. What would a raw type mean then? You can make up whatever meaning it has to satisfy yourself.

but they already do that.  raw types mean whatever you want and that's why we have these problems.

But I think I understand - we need raw types because of old code.  in order to accommodate them we need type erasure,  and the example in the OP is a problem of raw types and therefore indirectly of type erasure.

what do you mean by breaks in "above code compiles with a warning, but breaks at runtime" ? The posted code, if put inside a method (or in jshell), will run with no problems -- it will eventually throw an ClassCastException, if retrieving the added element from stringList as a String (e.g. String s = stringList.get(0) or System.out.println(stringList.get(0)))


My confusion is, we do type checking BEFORE type erasure occurs...

In this particular example, you are using raw types, so there is no type-checking on the type parameter either.
Before generics were added to Java, there were not type parameters in the code, but people still want code from back then to compile, so some parts of type-checking has to be disabled for raw types.
Without type erasure, raw types, which are the erased forms of parameterised types, wouldn't exist either, so the question is moot.

You talk about "removing type erasure" as if type erasure is some additive feature to the language. It is not. The compiler is just doing what it has always been doing since before generics exist - not emitting generic type information of local variables into the class file, because the JVM doesn't support generic types.
What would change if the JVM did support generic types, is that exceptions could be thrown at runtime much earlier. Suppose you are casting some variable of type Object to a List<String>. Suppose the variable actually stores a List<Integer>. The JVM can check that the cast is invalid at runtime and throw an exception right there where the cast is. In reality the JVM cannot do this, and will throw an exception only when you try to get a String out of that List<Integer>, which is potentially much later.
